# MEAN Stack app authorization - register seems to by trying to login

Tags: authentication, registration, mean-stack

When I try to register as a new user I get an error message saying invalid username or password which makes me think the app is trying to login when it should be trying to register.

The form:

```
form(class='form-auth' ng-submit='register()')
  p(class='text-warning'){{error_message}}
  label(for='email') Email
  input(type="email", ng-model='users.email', name="email", placeholder='Email')
  label(for='password') Password
  input(type="password", ng-model='users.password', name="password", placeholder='Password')
  input(type="submit" class='submitBtn' value='Go')
```

The 'register' controller (in file 'myApp.js' in the public Javascript directory)

```
app.controller('authController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){
  $scope.user = {email: '', password: ''};
  $scope.error_message = '';
  $scope.register = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $location.path('/');
    }
    else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
    }
  });
 };
});
```

I've got auth and passport in the main app.js file. I have a login function above the register one but it seems to be closed properly. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-model of the inputs should be "user.email, user.password" instead of "users.email, users.password" like its in your controller `$scope.user`.

Like $scope.users doesnt exist, empty values are sent to the backend.